# IndexError: list index out of range - Why does my movement sensor crash if it doesn't detect movement or it detects too much of it?

Tags: python, opencv, pygame, computer-vision

I have been building a movement sensor using python and pygame, it basically takes a picture of your camera footage, compares the RGB value of every pixel to the last picture taken and displays the pixels that have changed in the pygame screen. For some reason if it detects too much movement eg you cover the camera, or if it detects too litte eg you stop moving for a while it will crash.

code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame.camera
import pygame.image
import numpy as np
import cv2

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

cameras = pygame.camera.list_cameras()

print("Using camera %s ..." % cameras[0])

cam1 = pygame.camera.Camera(cameras[0])
cam1.start()

img1 = cam1.get_image()

flags = DOUBLEBUF
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500), flags, 4)
frame = 0

def take_screen_shot():
    global frame
    save_file = str(frame)+'.png'#save file
    pygame.image.save(img1, save_file)

def image_proccesing():
    global frame
    global counter
    if frame >= 1:
        img1 = cv2.imread(str(frame - 1)+'.png', 0)
        img2 = cv2.imread(str(frame)+'.png', 0)
        sub = cv2.subtract(img1, img2)

        coords = np.argwhere(sub > 100)#checks if the pixels have a difference bigger than 100

        coords_list = coords.tolist()#converts the array into a list

        x = list(list(zip(*coords_list))[0])#grabs the first value, in this case x coordenates
        y = list(list(zip(*coords_list))[1])#grabs the first value, in this case y coordenates

        for i in range(len(x)):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), pygame.Rect(y[i], x[i], 1, 1))
        x.clear()
        y.clear()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while 1:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pygame.event.set_allowed(KEYDOWN)
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            pygame.camera.quit()

    img1 = cam1.get_image().convert()
    take_screen_shot()
    image_proccesing()
    clock.tick(15)
    pygame.display.update()
    frame += 1
```

error:

```
    x = list(list(zip(*coords_list))[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: have you considered **why** that expression might fail? have you run this in a debugger and inspected the variables at the time of the exception?

Comment: The coords array is empty here. Or there is no movement, or the program incorrectly thinks that there is none.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out the error, I had to check if the files had any values. I did this by changing the `image_proccesing` function.

image_proccesing:

```
global frame
    global counter
    if frame >= 1:
        img1 = cv2.imread('screenshots\\'+str(frame - 1)+'.png', 0)
        img2 = cv2.imread('screenshots\\'+str(frame)+'.png', 0)
        sub = cv2.subtract(img1, img2)

        coords = np.argwhere(sub > 100)
        coords_list = coords.tolist()
        if coords_list:
            x = list(list(zip(*coords_list))[0])
            y = list(list(zip(*coords_list))[1])

            for i in range(len(x)):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), pygame.Rect(y[i], x[i], 1, 1))
                if (x[i] > values[0][0] and x[i] < values[1][0]):
                    if (y[i] > values[1][1] and y[i] < values[0][1]):
                        print('ayo')
            x.clear()
            y.clear()
```